# Python Django templates - navigate to a file with physical path

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I have these files

```
root folder
.... app
........ templates
............ app
................ index.html
................ js.js
...
...
```

and in the code, I want to be able to do something like this

```
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

and I have already tried this (which I found in the Django docs)

```
<script src="{{ static('js.js') }}"></script>
```

but it returned error -

> "Could not parse the remainder: '('js.js')' from 'static('js.js')'"

So how can I navigate to a file, with the physical path? (which normally, (without Django) is the default way)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `js.js` is in templates folder?...It should be in a separate folder called `static` usually?

Comment: Read the documentation. It is short, concise and very helpful. You will not get too far like this.

Comment: You **definitely** did not see that syntax in the Django docs.

Comment: I'll check the docs again, maybe I missed something.. There is a specific page that I should read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put statically served files (IE JS,CSS,Images, etc) in your [static folder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/)

You can also [change the root path for your static folder, too](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#deployment)

In a Django app, your folder structure does not determine what resources requests receive. Django now handles routing incoming requests to the appropriate resources, derived from your templates, python code, and static files.

[Django-Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/) can do some of the heavy-lifting in making your app directories, among other functions.

Comment: oh ok, `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` do the work. Thanks!
And what in Django-Admin - which command?